# Parallelize search for a filename with keyword in python

Tags: python, multithreading

i have a Directory with lot of files and Folders in it. The function which i wrote takes a  lot of time to search for the files with a particular keyword. It works but i want to make it efficient and faster. i was thinking of multiprocessing or threading.

But i know that threading does not work for nested for Loops. So i am stuck in figuring out how to use the multithreading module for this Problem.

The code which i wrote is as follows:

```
LIST.delete(0,END) # this is a list view
usePATH = '/nfzcae/nvh_mdp/Messdatenbank_Powertrain'
fileLevels = [] # code of interest is below

for path, dirs, f in os.walk(usePATH):
    for d in dirs:
        for f in glob.iglob(os.path.join(path, d,'*COMPARE.mat')):
            if 'COMPARE.mat' in f:                                          # if 'COMPARE.mat' in f and not 'MIN' in f and not 'MAX' in f / if 'COMPARE.mat' in f )   # if 'COMPARE.mat' in f and not 'MIN' in f and not 'MAX' in f
                fileLevels.append(f.split('/'))                             # Split path string at all '/'
                LIST.insert(END,f)                                          # Insert path with name string into the listbox
                LIST.update_idletasks()                                     # Update listbox after each element added
                nr = LIST.size()                                            # Get current number of files in listbox
                VAR.set(nr)                                                 # Set number of files as a variable for label
                LIST.see(END)                                               # See last element added
                FILE_LIST.append(f)
            else:
                pass                                                        # Do nothing
LIST.insert(END,'Search finished')                                          # Marks conclusion of search process
```

It is actually made for a GUI Button. I want to make this code faster. Any ideas ? I am having an idea on These lines:

1) get all the Sub directories names in a list
2) parallel pool now using the list and write a function which checks the Sub Folders for the file Name containing the keyword

Will this work??

**P.S: The Folder has lot of subdirectories (more than 1000)**

thank you

Comment: I am using Linux as well Windows. The code should be used in both and i am using python 3.5

Comment: I use APScheduler (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/APScheduler/) to do multithreading, will post a proper answer when I have time.

Comment: `os.scandir` (new in 3.5) claims to speed directory walks up, but you also need to determine where your code's time is being spent.

Comment: Yeah i check it now using timeit, it seems that the nested for is taking time. Now i will check with scandir @holdenweb

Comment: `profile` is a rather less blunt instrument for determining program hot spots than `timeit`. But I haven't studied your code closely enough to determine whether it's optimal. You might get better responses on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ which exists precisely to help people improve thier code.